# Java: Storing numbers in vector, transfer to array, then take primes from array and store in another vector

Tags: java, arrays, vector, primes

I'm going to post the question and then the code that I currently have done. I feel like I'm pretty close to getting it but I'm stuck at one part I just can't seem to figure out. Here goes:

The question: Create a Vector that stores N numbers. Input N non-negative numbers through the console into the Array. Then create another Vector that stores only M prime numbers from the N numbers.

My code so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class VectorPrimes {

    public static Vector<Integer> inputVc = new Vector<Integer>();
    public static Vector<Integer> primeVc = new Vector<Integer>(inputVc);

    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        boolean prime = true;
        for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i+= 2) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return prime;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("This program will take input of positive numbers and output"
                        + " prime numbers, if any, from the input numbers.");

        System.out
                .println("Input a positive number to check for prime numbers: ");



        boolean looping = true;

        while (looping) {
            System.out
                    .println("Input '0' to finish inputting numbers and print the primes.");
            String userin = scan.nextLine();
            int input = Integer.parseInt(userin);

            if (input != 0) {

                System.out.println("Enter next number: ");

                inputVc.add(input);
            } else if (input == 0) {
                //Integer[] inputArray = inputVc.toArray(new Integer[inputVc.size()]);
                looping = false;



                System.out.println(inputVc);
                System.out.print(primeVc);
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I'm sure it's not the best way to do it, but that's what I have so far. To be clear, I'm having trouble getting the inputted numbers from the input vector (inputVc) to go into the array (inputArray) and then storing the prime numbers in the prime vector (primeVc) and printing them. I have tried 3 or 4 different ways but I can't get anything to store in the primeVc vector, it just keeps printing blank.

I'm not asking for the code, what I'm trying to figure out is strictly how to get the prime numbers inputted into the primeVc vector and then print it. Of course the inputVc numbers need to be run through the isPrime method and then added to the primeVc vector if true, but I'm pretty sure that's where I'm having my problem.

What do you guys see?? I'm definitely missing something and cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: do u really want to use vector ?

Comment: The question says "Create a Vector that stores N numbers. Input N non-negative numbers through the console into the Array..." This requirement states that you need to read in the numbers from the console and store them in the Array (read Vector). You don't need to copy from a Vector to an Array before you extract the prime's. Just read in each number and push it onto the Vector.

Comment: Sounds like homework for me.

Comment: Here is a version in Java that returns all primes until a number passed in, it uses the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm  http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=102&t=1938#p24878  see if you can work with that to incorporate into your code

Comment: If you have gotten the imputed values in your vector just loop over it and call isprime for each element and add if true? Btw the isprime method looks very wrong as well....

Comment: you are not calling the isPrime() function..

Comment: If your teacher really asks you to use the Vector class, tell him we're not in 1998 anymore. It's been 14 years we shouldn't be using Vector anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like:

```
//...
if (input != 0) {
    System.out.println("Enter next number: ");
    inputVc.add(input);
    if (isPrime(input))
        primeVc.add(input);
}
//...
```

Also you can create `while(true)` loop and simply `break` it when you will get `0`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really should have stepped away and relaxed for a bit considering I missed something so simple. Merry Christmas and happy new years!

Comment: No problem. You too! :) But consider also your `isPrime` method cause it's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to call your functon `isPrime`then if returned value is true then add it to your second list
and other thing, your function `isPrime` won't work, your initial value of 'i' is 2, then you are incrementing it by 2, so it will return value `true` for each odd number